# Using HTML tag in vba code to customize generated email

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to manipule html tags to customize an generated email.
I don't have any struggle to use organizing tags such as `<p>` or `<br />`...
However it is when I try to modify font I am struggling.
Here an example of the `String` I am sending :

```vb
messsage = "<section> <p> Madame, Monsieur, <br /> </p> <p> Blablablabla. <br /> </p> <p> <span font-size="" 16px; font-weight: bold;""> blablabla : </span>" & Sheets(4).Range("A" & i + 1).Value & " </p> <br /> <p> blablabla.<br />blablala. </p> <br /> <p> blabla : " & objDict.Items(i) & " </p> <br /> <p> blabla </p> </section> "
```

It is `<span font-size="" 16px; font-weight: bold;""> blablabla : </span>` I am getting wrong.
This gives me no font modification.

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Comment: Try `<span style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold;">Bla</span>`

Comment: In vba  I need to escape ``"`` character like this ``""`` or ``'"``. So I don't thin this will work

Comment: Then `<span style=""font-size:16px; font-weight: bold;"">` works?

Comment: ...or use single-quotes, which are also valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my error. I was trying to use CSS in HTML but Outlook doesn't seem to process it.
I managed to use genuine HTML tags liek this :

```vb
<p> <font size=""4""> <b> Blablalbla </b> </font> </p>
```

So instead of using `<span style=""font-size:16px>` liek suggested in comments, the tag `<font size=""4""> </font>`  is doing the same.
However  HTML tags are limited to what CSS tags can offer.